# using SVGs with scripts in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have an svg that contains a script tag that is interactive and reacts to key presses. I am unable so far to get the svg to work in react.js.

I am able to display the svg statically using an img element:

`<img src={*svg code*} alt="svg title" width="400px"/>`

doing it this way however doesn't run the script element in the svg and thus it is not interactive. I also tried using the svgr package, and followed the website guide exactly:

`npm install --save-dev @svgr/core`

`import { transform } from '@svgr/core'`

```
const jsCode = await transform(
  svgCode,
  { icon: true },
  { componentName: 'MyComponent' },
)
```

when I change variable names and run this I get errors like:

./node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.mjs
Can't import the named export 'TraceMap' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

and a bunch of other errors but with "TraceMap" replaced with something else

side note: in my  element in my svg, I have

`type="text/javascript"`

since the errors say 'from non EcmaScript...' I changed it to

`type="application/ecmascript"`

I get the same errors either way.

Im not sure what the difference is, its just the two versions I am aware of.

Anybody know what Im doing wrong? I believe the svgr is the solution somehow, but not the way im doing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not sure it works for script tags but maybe using `object` will make it work.  https://moshfeu.github.io/links-inside-svg/

Comment: It works!!! thanks!! 
something like this works for anyone else wondering:

```<object id="svg" data={base64uri} type="image/svg+xml" width="400px"></object> ```